# Swift ^ Operation on Double

Tags: swift, binary, double, calculator, operation

I am trying to solve a challenge but the code keeps failing.
I need to perform a ^ operation on doubles. Challenge was if I call a function calculate(3,2,^) then I should get the result 9.

I tried the below code but failed with this error:

> error: binary operator '^' cannot be applied to two 'Double' operands

Below is my Code:

```
func calc(a: Double, b: Double, op: Character) -> Double {
var c:Double
c = 0
if op == "+"
{
    c =  a + b
}
else if op == "-"
{
    c =  a - b
}
else if op == "*"
{
    c =  a * b
}
else if op == "/"
{
    c =  a / b
}
else if op == "%"
{
    let rem = a.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: b)
    c = rem
}

else if op == "^"
{
    let z = a ^ b
     c = z
}
return c
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^` is the [bitwise XOR operator](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html#ID33), not exponentiation.

Use the `pow(_:_:)` method instead:

```
else if op == "^"
{
    c = pow(a, b)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try to use boucle For

```
  for (let index = 0; index < b; index++) {
    c= a*index;

}
```